# TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Tags: node.js, bots, discord.js

I want the bot to change the color of the roles and it gives an error

```
client.guilds.get(servers[index]).roles.find('name', config.roleName).setColor(rainbow[place])
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined
    at Timeout.changeColor [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\1\Desktop\discord1\Role.js:29:38)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:466:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:267:5)
```

Here is my code:

```
function changeColor() {
  for (let index = 0; index < servers.length; ++index) {        
    client.guilds.get(servers[index]).roles.find('name', config.roleName).setColor(rainbow[place])
        .catch(console.error);      
    if(config.logging){
      console.log([ColorChanger] Changed color to ${rainbow[place]} in server: ${servers[index]});
    }
    if(place == (size - 1)){
      place = 0;
    }else{
      place++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because `client.guilds.get('<id>')` expects an exact guild id passed in as a `String`. See the comments in red under the [`.find`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) method:

> All collections used in Discord.js are mapped using their id property, and if you want to find by id you should use the get method. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) for details.

Therefore, the data stored at `server[index]` (in the 3rd line of your code) must not be a valid guild id.